# Stream the audio of Flash video only

Tags: flash, audio, streaming

Is it possible to have a Flash player that only plays the AAC audio of Flash video (FLV file)? In other words, we need the video muted and only play the audio.

Comment: If you plan to save bandwidth like that, then note that it‘s not possible..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, FLV files do not contain AAC audio.  (MPEG4/F4V files may though.)

What about making a video player that is 0x0 in size?